# Weird Resolution on Android Emulator with Visual Studio

Tags: android, windows, visual-studio, xamarin, emulation

I'll get straight to it, this is what's happening:

[image: Screenshot]

Any way to fix this? It's the default Visual Studio/Xamarin emulator.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio/Xamarin & Windows OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 with Visual Studio Community 2015 (14.0.25431.01 Update 3), with the newest Xamarin (don't think that matters as much, it's an emulator issue, not a Xamarin one).

Comment: Go to the AVD Manager and edit this AVD to use a different `device model` or when starting the AVD manually you can hit `Scale display to real size`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I can't be bothered to deal with this anymore. Downloaded the last available version of the Xamarin Android player (which they are, apparently, discontinuing) from https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/.